# MySQL - Conditional COUNT with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to refine a query that I am currently using:

```
SELECT `puid`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT `droid_v`) AS DROID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT `sig_v`) AS sig,
       SUM(NoExt)  AS hits
       FROM temp
       GROUP BY `puid`
```

And I need to get it to only count `droid_v` where `droid_V` is greater than 0. Is it possible to condition the count in this way? At the moment, it is counting zero values as countable, and I can't really change the zeros to `null` values.

I do not need to know the count value for `droid_V` = 0, I only need to count it if it has a number greater than 0. That number will always be either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.

---

I have tried:

```
SELECT `puid`,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `droid_v` > 0 THEN 1 END) AS DROID,
   COUNT(DISTINCT `sig_v`) AS sig,
   SUM(`NoExt`)  AS hits
   FROM temp
   GROUP BY `puid`
```

But this gives a binary result (either 0 or 1) not the count I am expecting.

example output =

```
puid            DROID   sig     hits
No PUID         1       1        252
x-fmt/92        1       5       1008
```

anticipated output:

```
puid            DROID   sig     hits
No PUID         1       1        252
x-fmt/92        3       5       1008
```

Sample data:

```
id;puid;droid_v;sig_v;speed;Ext;NoExt;tally


1;"No PUID";"3";"v13";"SLOW";"0";"63";"63"
2;"x-fmt/92";"3";"v13";"SLOW";"63";"0";"63"
3;"x-fmt/92";"3";"v37";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
4;"x-fmt/92";"3";"v45";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
5;"x-fmt/92";"3";"v49";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
6;"x-fmt/92";"3";"v50";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126" 
7;"x-fmt/92";"5";"v13";"SLOW";"63";"0";"63"
8;"No PUID";"5";"v13";"SLOW";"0";"63";"63"
9;"x-fmt/92";"5";"v37";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
10;"x-fmt/92";"5";"v45";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
11;"x-fmt/92";"5";"v49";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
12;"x-fmt/92";"5";"v50";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
13;"No PUID";"6";"v13";"FAST";"0";"63";"63"
14;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v13";"SLOW";"63";"0";"63"
15;"No PUID";"6";"v13";"SLOW";"0";"63";"63"
16;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v13";"FAST";"63";"0";"63"
17;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v37";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
18;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v37";"FAST";"63";"63";"126"
19;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v45";"FAST";"63";"63";"126"
20;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v45";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
21;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v49";"FAST";"63";"63";"126"
22;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v49";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
23;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v50";"FAST";"63";"63";"126"
24;"x-fmt/92";"6";"v50";"SLOW";"63";"63";"126"
```

Comment: can you add a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: from the example you provided, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If droid_v can only be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, then COUNT(DISTINCT) will never return more than 5, since there are only five possible values. Is that what you want? If so, then try this:

```
SELECT puid, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN droid_v > 0 THEN droid_v ELSE 0 END) - 1 AS droid /* -1 for the case where droid_v is 0 */
     , COUNT(DISTINCT sig_v) AS sig
     , SUM(NoExt)  AS hits
```

**Update:** Oops, sorry, the above is not quite right as there might not *be* a zero.
It should be:

```
SELECT puid, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN droid_v > 0 THEN droid_v END) AS droid
```

If, on the other hand, you want a count of all the rows where droid_v > 0, then I think you want this:

```
SELECT puid, SUM(CASE WHEN droid_v > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS droid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT sig_v) AS sig
     , SUM(NoExt)  AS hits
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats the one - I was poking away at it prior to your change, and trying to figure out what was wrong. You are correct, it migth not be Zero. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 19):

Just use a sum

so if you want to group something check this out

```
select city, sum( case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end ) as male,
sum( case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end ) as female
from person
group by city
```

simple as this :D

Comment: This is the better answer. Additionally you can use MYSQL IF instead of CASE. For example,

`SUM( IF( gender = 'male' , 1, 0 ) )`

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT
  `puid`,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `droid_v` > 0 THEN `droid_v` END) AS DROID,
   COUNT(DISTINCT `sig_v`) AS sig,
   SUM(NoExt)  AS hits
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the question to respond to your idea.

Comment: My initial answer was wrong despite your clear question. See revised answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
SELECT puid,
SUM(droid_v > 0) AS DROID,
COUNT(DISTINCT sig_v) AS sig,
SUM(`NoExt`)  AS hits
FROM t
GROUP BY puid
```

However, it is not clear if you want to count the distinct or not. If you want to count the distinct values then:

```
SELECT puid,
COUNT(if(droid_v > 0, droid_v, null)) AS DROID,
COUNT(DISTINCT sig_v) AS sig,
SUM(`NoExt`)  AS hits
FROM t
GROUP BY puid
```

Comment: Thanks for having a look - thats close, but its loses the distinct function that I need (sorry if I didn't make that clear)

Answer (score 2):

add this to the query

```
WHERE droid_v > 0
```