# MySQL count specific datetimes

Tags: mysql

i want to count rows with a single database-query.

My Database has following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `sender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `receiver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_send` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_read` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `message` longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `sender` (`sender`),
    KEY `receiver` (`receiver`),
    CONSTRAINT `receiver` FOREIGN KEY (`receiver`) REFERENCES `ctn_users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `sender` FOREIGN KEY (`sender`) REFERENCES `ctn_users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample-Data:**

```
INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES (1, 0, 1, '2017-3-26 09:22:39', '0000-0-0 00:00:00', 'Welcome!', 'Hey!');
```

> **INFORMATION:** The user with the ID `0` is a System-User; Do not ask for the auto-incremental mistake from the users-table

My Problem is to count specific values, for example **i want following query-result**:

```
read    unread    send
0       1         0
```

Here is my first try:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(???) AS `read`,
    COUNT(???) AS `unread`,
    COUNT(???) AS `send`
FROM
    `messages`
WHERE
    `receiver`=1
```

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN yourConditon = read END)`and so on but what is that condition doesnt appear in your question,I`m guessing it has something to do with the other tables

Comment: `send` = the count of messages, what the user had sent. Sorry between the **t** and **d**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `case` in the `count`,  and to move the condition from your `where` to the `case`

```
select  count(case when receiver = 1 and time_read > time_sent then id end) as read
        count(case when receiver = 1 and time_send > time_read then id end) as unread 
        count(case when sender = 1 then id end) send
from    messages
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know this method so far :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to [count fields with condition (Conditional Count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560432/mysql-conditional-count-with-group-by) , So we can count read messages with this `count()` functional:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN time_read > '0000-0-0 00:00:00' THEN time_read ELSE 0 END) as ReedMessages
```

this query is not returning final results, because of no `sender` and `reciver` condition in `count(condition)`. (see Stefano Zanini answer)

We can use `Sum` function too:

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when `receiver` = 1 and time_read > '0000-0-0 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as read
  SUM(case when `receiver` = 1 and time_read = '0000-0-0 00:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) as unread 
  SUM(case when `sender` = 1 then 1 end) as send
FROM `tblName`
```